# What does "earth" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> Generators mounted on the same frame as the equipment they are
>   supplying should be insulated from earth.

Does it mean "soil" or "grounding (electrical connection to the earth)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means they should not be ***grounded***, another term for which is ***earthed***.

Comment: Then "earth" means grounding, am I right?

Comment: In this case, judging from context, almost certainly. It's another term for the same thing. In British English at least, we almost always talk about "electrical earth", "earth wire", "is that equipment earthed?" and so on.